# Error converting Nvarchar data type to datetime from VB.NET

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a problem regarding dates from my program to a stored procedure in SQL.

My program takes a date from the excel spreadsheet and parses it as such:

```
            tempDate = Date.FromOADate(exWS.Cells(exRow, myMatchedColumns(2)).value)
            Dim format() = {"dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"}
            dueDate = Date.ParseExact(tempDate, format,
            System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
            Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)
```

dueDate is 'DATE' variable so I'm assuming at this point the 'dueDate' is a universal Date object. I think this was the best way to parse BOTH English regional date and **Polish** dates, since this will be used on a Polish machine.

However, when sending values to my stored procedure:

```
        mySQLString = "EXEC bsp.PartPrice_sp " & _
            "'" & dueDate & "', " & _
            "'" & myPartID & "', " & _
            "'" & currency & "'"
```

English sends `EXEC bsp.PartPrice_sp '01/09/2015', 'L555', 'USD'` which returns the price.

Polish sends `EXEC bsp.PartPrice_sp '2015-09-01', 'L555', 'USD'` which incurs the error:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

I understand the error, but the next execution of the stored procedure, the Polish machine sent `2015-09-10` which returned a price fine. I'm guessing since `2015-10-09` is still within range but interestingly it returned the correct price for 10th September 2015.

Nevertheless I'm struggling to find a universal way of executing the stored procedure in both English and Polish. Any help you can give to parse the dates correctly which also makes SQL happy would be awesome.

Thanks.

Program written in VB .NET.

P.S If I change the @duedate in the stored procedure from nvarchar to datetime, I get an:

> Error converting data type varchar to datetime.

Error, which I'm guessing is from the English format. Many thanks.

Comment: Try `duedate = duedate.ToString("d", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's looking good except the ToString function takes an integer not string and doesn't accept a second parameter? I'm getting a Too Many Arguments error. Thanks.

Comment: I did not get you..!!(_ToString function takes an integer not string and doesn't accept a second parameter?_ clarify this) and the method is  working w/o any errors see [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QMakBO) and try this aslo `duedate = Format(duedate, "dd/MM/yyyy")`

Answer (score 0):

Date formats in inline non-parameterised queries are one of those things that can drive you spare in my experience.

So -

1. If at all possible issue a SqlCommand with a collection of SqlParameters, into which you add the actual Date-typed .Net variables. Much safer.
2. If you really have to keep the inline SQL for some reason, *never* pass in regionalised date formats. They reliably break for odd reasons. Ideally send the server YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.ms, but to be safe run that through a centralised function - partly it's easier than making sure you're calling the right .ToString() format in all places correctly, partly I've in the past had occasional servers complain even at that format.